# How to insert values into one column based on values of another column for each row?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```sql
# table schema
CREATE TABLE `ref_str` (
  `ref_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_str` varchar(4096) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

This is current data:

```
+--------+--------------------+
| ref_id | ref_str            |
+--------+--------------------+
|   NULL | [5] www.NCCN.com   |
|   NULL | [4] www.nhc.gov.cn |
|   NULL | [14] www.hc.gov.cn |
|   NULL | [146] someh.gov.cn |
+--------+--------------------+
```

And I want to iteratively insert into `ref_id` column the int value inside `[]` of `ref_str` of same row.

The result should look like:

```
+--------+--------------------+
| ref_id | ref_str            |
+--------+--------------------+
|    5   | [5] www.NCCN.com   |
|    4   | [4] www.nhc.gov.cn |
|   14   | [14] www.hc.gov.cn |
|  146   | [146] someh.gov.cn |
+--------+--------------------+
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.32.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE ref_str
SET ref_id = 0 + TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM ref_str);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a40a34f2fa71994e4a46602e0bce570b)

Firstly we remove leading bracket. Then we convert the value implicitly to a number - non-numeric tail is simply cut off.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` here, for example:

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ref_str, ']', 1), 2) AS ref_id,
    ref_str
FROM ref_str;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo